# Charset problem MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I can't get swedish character like å ä ö in my tables when i use MySQL tables in my localhost. I use DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 when I create the tables, but not working! All files with the PHP code are in UTF-8.

Preciate some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need it on your client as well. I've found this weird issue when inserting UTF-8 characters (Japanese) into a MySQL database which can be solved by running the query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Immediately after connecting to the database.

Edit: Here is an example of using `SET NAMES 'utf8'` after connecting to a database:

```
$db = new mysqli($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass'], $config['db_name']);
if(!$db || $db->connect_error)
{
  // Some error code handling here
}
else
{
  // need this for JP inserts
  $db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
```

Comment: I only get error when I insert it! Perhaps I do wrong. Could you be kind to the show how the connecting line to the database would look like with SET NAMES..... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working! :) Perhaps there is some way to correct this with MySQl Workbench?

Comment: @user637364 You're quite welcome. I'm just glad someone didn't have to go through as much searching as I did to find this solution :)